# ¿ Como pasar bloques de memoria (punteros) desde C++ a C#?

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d

Tengo un pequeño problema que espero que podáis ayudarme.

Tengo este código en `c++`:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
unsigned char* ProcessFrame() {

    VideoCapture cam;
    cam.open(0);

    Mat imagen;
    unsigned char* result;
    cam >> imagen;
    flip(imagen, imagen, 0);
    result = new unsigned char[imagen.cols*imagen.rows*4];
    memcpy(result, imagen.data, imagen.cols*imagen.rows*4);
    return result;
}
```

Que quiero usarlo en Unity, con el siguiente código:

```
        byte[] imgData = ProcessFrame();

        Debug.Log(imgData.Length);
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(320, 240, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        tex.LoadRawTextureData(imgData);
        tex.Apply();
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

El problema es que me responde siempre:

> No texture data provided to LoadRawTextureData.

Parece ser que desde C++ no se pueden pasar punteros *tal cual* a C#.

Comment: No soy experto en Unity,pero por descartar:estás seguro de que `ProcessFrame` devuelve correctamente datos en `imgData`?

Comment: si, utilizando PInvoke es posible añadiendo 
    [DllImport("NativoPrincipio.dll")]
    public static extern byte[] ProcessFrame();

Comment: No me refiero a si es posible...veo que tienes un `Debug.Log` de `imgData.Length`..que te devuelve?

Comment: me devuelve 0, pero viendo el codigo de c++ me tendria que devolver otra cosa. No entiendo realmente poque me devuelve 0

Comment: Pues ahi está el problema, que `ProcessFrame` no te está devolviendo datos.A ver si algun experto en c++ puede revisar ese código.

Comment: @UrkoSanchezOrtiz ¿Has verificado que la función `ProcessFrame` devuelve datos si lo pruebas en C++?

Comment: ¿Para qué se crea una `Mat` en la que se copian datos si después lo que se devuelve es `result`? A ver si resulta que tienes que devolver otra cosa.

Comment: He progado ProcessFrame aparte en un programa en c++ y me devuelve 122800 que es lo que ocupa. Ahora lo integro en mi codigo c++ y ago que me muestre lo mismo y me devuelve 0.

Comment: @UrkoSanchezOrtiz Te he editado el título y un poco la pregunta. La encuentro interesante, y útil para otros. Espero que no te moleste.

Comment: Con el código que muestras es complicado de decir, pero... ¿no será que estás dejando sin inicializar algun elemento de la captura?

Answer (score 2):

> Parece ser que desde C++ no se pueden pasar punteros tal cual a C#.

Eso no es así.Pasar punteros de hecho es muy sencillo. El problema es obtener los datos a los que apunta ese puntero, ya que no estan delimitados. Para eso,es necesario conocer su tamaño. Existen varias opciones:

1.- Si el tamaño de los datos a pasar es siempre fijo(en tu caso `imagen.cols*imagen.rows*4`) simplemente puedes copiar esos datos en la parte C#

### Ejemplo:

-**Cabecera (archivo .h)**

```
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport)unsigned char *ProcessFrame(); }
```

-**Codigo C++ (archivo .cpp)**

```
unsigned char* ProcessFrame() {

    VideoCapture cam;
    cam.open(0);

    Mat imagen;
    unsigned char* result;
    cam >> imagen;
    flip(imagen, imagen, 0);
    result = new unsigned char[imagen.cols*imagen.rows*4];
    memcpy(result, imagen.data, imagen.cols*imagen.rows*4);
    return result;
}
```

-**C#**

```
var imgPointer = ProcessFrame();
int tamaño=t; //t es el valor de imagen.cols*imagen.rows*4
byte[] imgData=new byte[tamaño];     
Marshal.Copy(imgPointer , imagen, 0, tamaño);
```

2.- En caso de que el tamaño de los datos no sea fijo, una posible solución es almacenar este valor en una variable estática y crear un método en C++ que devuelva este valor. El resto del código sería igual al que te he puesto en el punto anterior.

---

Es bueno comentar que el código en c++ tienes una fuga de memoria, ya que asignas memoria a `result` y no la liberas en ningun momento. El problema es que no puedes hacerlo antes de que se obtenga la imagen en el lado C#, ya que si no dejaría de estar disponible. Una posible solución sería crear otro método en C++ que libere esa memoria, y llamarlo desde C# una vez obtenidos los datos.